# Как из обычной картинки сделать иконку?

Tags: photoshop, html, css

Как из обычной картинки сделать иконку и задать разрешение?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, а то не могу найти иконку, а сделать просто из картинки вообще не знаю как.

Comment: Вы на форуме всего четыре дня, но успели задать 15-ть бессмысленных вопроса. Пока вы рекордсмен по отрицательному рейтингу, но есть все шансы стать абсолютным чемпионом, если, как вам советовали, не откроете книги для "чайников" по HTML, CSS и прочим опасностям. Вариант второй - если учиться в ваши планы не входит, то дорога вам на [ucoz][1]... хотя и там надо хоть что-то знать.

   [1]: http://www.ucoz.ru/

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйся [этим сайтом](http://favicon.ru).

Answer (score 1):

Я так полагаю, Вы о теге `<img>`. Этот тег имеет обязательные 2 атрибута (src,alt). Чтобы задать размеры картинок Вам необходимы 2 атрибута `height`(высота изображение в `px`), `width` (ширина изображения в `px`).
**Пример использование в html 4.01:**

```
   <img src='website.ru/1.jpg' alt='Описание изображения, если оно отсутствует' width='150' height='150' />
```

**Пример использования в html 5:**

```
<img src='website.ru/1.jpg' alt='Описание изображения, если оно отсутствует' style='width:150px;height:150px;' />
```

Comment: да не надо уже) разобрался давным давно

Comment: Атрибуты с размерами корректны для html5 же?